# Where to install SQL on EC2

Tags: sql-server, aws, amazon-ec2

If SQL Server and it's system databases are installed on an EC2 local drive, will they be recovered in a crash?

My understanding is nothing but temporary files and the OS should be on the local storage but I may not understand EC2 recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to follow best practices for your data and log files, whether you’re running on EC2 or on-premise. Think of EC2 just as any other VM, it just happens to be running in AWS.

The big difference being how you provision storage. You’ll want to provision a persisted volume in the web console and mount that to the server where you have SQL installed. Once you have the new drive letter available in the OS, you can create your data files there, instead of in the sys drive.

Make sure to choose the proper storage type for SQL Server. While you’re at it, make sure to provision storage for TempDB.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Brendan. Would you install SQL program files to the local drive or to the attached volume? Currently, SQL is on the ephemeral storage along with master, msdb, model, and system database, all user databases are on other EBS volumes. My concern is if the host system gets terminated for whatever reason, I would lose my SQL install along with the security configurations, etc. Perhaps an EC2 snapshot would suffice for bringing up a new instance in a disaster recovery situation?

Comment: When I build a SQL Server, I usually have a dedicated LUN for each of the following: SQL binaries and sys database, user data files, user and TempDB log files, TempDB data files, and  one for Ad-hoc backups.